# How to speed up a very slow MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very slow MySQL syntax which is basically unusable since the table has grown to over 5000 entries. It takes more than 30 sec so the server sends error code and quits.

The syntax is:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    user_id, 
    date 
FROM
    table 
WHERE 
    id IN (
           SELECT 
               MAX(id)
           FROM 
               table
           GROUP BY date
          ) 
    AND 
    company_id = '1'
    AND 
    date > '1473700785'
    AND
    complete = '1'
    AND
    name = "random string" 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Structure:

```
id - int(11)
user_id - int(10)
company_id - int(11)
date - varchar(20)
complete - varchar(2)
name - varchar(75)
```

Do you have any idea what could be slowing it? It used to function as expected with a much smaller table size (under 1000 entries).

Comment: though tsql and MySQL has similar syntax, but they are different suites, back to question, try to use join instead of `in`, and check indexes.

Comment: You can use indexing and apply it on user_id

Comment: You have any indexes on the table?

Comment: Thanks Chetan, this was exactly what was needed in this situation. I did not even know indexes had such an application, so I feel like a complete amateur which of course I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from subquery (like below), the best method is indexing. Like what most people here suggested

```
SELECT id, user_id, date 
FROM table min

--sub queries sometimes run faster than IN / NOT IN 

JOIN (
          SELECT SELECT MAX(id) 
          FROM table 
          GROUP BY date
      ) 
          max on max.id = min.id

WHERE min.company_id = '1' 
 AND min.date > '1473700785' 
 AND min.complete = '1' 
 AND min.name = "random string" 

ORDER BY min.id ASC
```

Comment: I have to be honest, I did not try your solution yet, as my question was solved by indexing a couple of variables. But it helped me to understand the scope and is simple enough so that I can understand and find additional answers where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need index for date field.
And you need store date as integer, because you use this expression

```
date > '1473700785'
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is good, but I don't see the need for a SUB-SELECT

```
SELECT 
    MAX(t.id) as id, 
    u.user_id, 
    t.date 
FROM table t
JOIN table u ON u.id=MAX(t.id )
WHERE 
    t.company_id = '1'
    AND 
    t.date > '1473700785'
    AND
    t. complete = '1'
    AND
    t.name = "random string" 
GROUP BY t.date
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```